# Como saltar un elemento de un range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola devs hay alguna manera de excluir el 10 de este rango con ruby.

```
is_active = (9..12).include?(step)
```

donde step es un atributo de un objeto

Answer (score 2):

Lo más sencillo sería utilizar una condición extra, donde se verifique que `step` no sea igual a 10:

```
is_active = step != 10 && (9..12).include?(step)
```